# Looking for a cheap, easy to find laser gain media?

Tags: classical-mechanics, photons, atomic-physics, reflection, laser

So I want to make my own home made laser, but I'm having trouble deciding on what gain media to use. I'm not an expert on lasers but I know the basics of how they work from reading online.

I want to get a cheap gain medium that will produce a visible light. Whats the best way I can get something like this? I don't know specifically what type of gain medium I should get either, I dont know which ones produce visible light. Crystal, gas, liquid? (I would prefer to use a solid one as they are easier to use.) I just don't know where to look or what to use.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is your budget?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's about purchasing an item rather than physics.

Comment: http://repairfaq.cis.upenn.edu/sam/laserfaq.htm#faqtoc may be of interest

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a nitrogen laser as described in [this article](http://technology.niagarac.on.ca/people/mcsele/lasers/LasersN2.htm) and in the articles referenced therein.  It can be made using easily scavenged parts.

The reason I suggest a nitrogen laser (which emits UV light) is because it can be made from scrap, low-tech parts. Making a HeNe laser is pretty easy but requires high quality dielectric mirrors, which are easy to obtain. For that matter, visible light diode lasers can be bought for less than a dollar. But if the point is to build a laser with one's own hands rather than buy a kit or a finished laser and if visible emission *per se* is not important, a nitrogen laser is a good home project.

Comment: Aren't nitrogen lasers usually UV? If you're going to do gas, Helium-Neon has been a stand-by for visible light lasers for *ages*. And you can—in prinicple—get green as well as red.

Comment: You're right on both counts.  The reason I suggested a nitrogen laser is because it truly can be made from scrap, low-tech parts.  Making a HeNe laser is pretty easy but requires high quality dielectric mirrors.  That said, high quality laser mirrors are very easy to obtain these days.  For that matter, visible light diode lasers can be bought for less than a dollar.  But ***if*** the point is to build a laser with one's own hands rather than buy a kit or a finished laser (and the point wasn't exactly spelled out by the OP), and if visible *per se* is not important, a nitrogen laser is good.

Comment: OK. Fair enough. But you might want to spell out the band in the post for clarity.